# Is pdftex 1.40.13 outputting malformed pdfs?

Tags: errors, pdftex, pdf

I have several preexisting projects that produced valid pdf output on versions of pdftex up to 1.40.10. Now with version 1.40.13 I'm getting pdfs that the iText library complains are malformed. My question is whether I'm analyzing the situation correctly and whether it looks like the bug is in pdftex or iText.

The following demonstrates the difference in behavior on two systems, one with the old version and one with the new. The pdftk utility parses the pdf using the iText library:

```
|||| LM  me $ pdflatex --version | head -1
pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
|||| LM  me $ pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode me >/dev/null
|||| LM  me $ pdftk me.pdf cat output /dev/null
|||| LM  me $ 

---- rintintin me $ pdflatex --version | head -1
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
---- rintintin me $ pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode me >/dev/null
---- rintintin me $ pdftk me.pdf cat output /dev/null
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   me.pdf
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

This is with identical (freshly synchronized) source files.

This doesn't happen with all my projects, and, e.g., I can't produce it with a simple "hello, world" document. I've posted the file me.pdf that generates the error here: http://www.lightandmatter.com/pdftk_bug/

Pdftk doesn't report the type of error, but it's possible to find out what it is by invoking an iText tool from the command line:

```
---- rintintin me $ java -cp /usr/share/java/itext1-1.4.jar com.lowagie.tools.plugins.InspectPDF me.pdf
trailer not found.
```

The old version of pdftex outputs pdf 1.4, the new 1.5. The iText library is supposed to be able to handle pdf versions up to 1.6.

Examining the ends of the two pdf files in a text editor, there does seem to be a clear difference in the trailers:

Pdf output by old version:

```
trailer
<< /Size 3577
/Root 3575 0 R
/Info 3576 0 R
/ID [<F3E9A772E7220505119484B4C1B5059E> <F3E9A772E7220505119484B4C1B5059E>] >>
startxref
38327286
%%EOF
```

Pdf output by the new version:

```
3499 0 obj <<
/Type /XRef
/Index [0 3500]
/Size 3500
/W [1 4 1]
/Root 3497 0 R
/Info 3498 0 R
/ID [<B51C8DB4F9B12A880DBBE0625164918E> <B51C8DB4F9B12A880DBBE0625164918E>]
/Length 9886
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x\3325\234w|\224U\376\2663!\275@z#      !!=\201\220\204^D\222^PR\200\320^RJ^R\322CHDAW]u-\253^B
...lots of binary data snipped for brevity...
w*\374;\233\344\231A\367H\230^?6\3120\233\356t\230\303^C\246\317c^E\362\314\213;^S\346\343\307d\230G7\223\353fr\335$
endstream
endobj
startxref
37919910
%%EOF
```

The second to last line is supposed to be a byte offset to the cross-reference section.

```
|||| LM  me $ od -a -j 38327286 me.pdf | head -1
222151766   x   r   e   f  nl   0  sp   3   5   7   7  nl   0   0   0   0

---- rintintin me $ od -a -j 37919910 me.pdf | head -1
220516246   3   4   9   9  sp   0  sp   o   b   j  sp   <   <  nl   /   T
```

In the output from the old version, the byte offset points to the string "xref," which seems right. In the output from the new version, it points to something that looks different, perhaps a new style of xref used in pdf 1.5? When I compile a simple "hello, world" document with the new pdftex, it has a format that looks similar to this, but iText doesn't choke on it.

I haven't dug into the pdf specs or the source code of iText, so I don't know whether this is actually a malformed pdf or if it's valid pdf 1.5 that iText just isn't accepting. Ghostscript and poppler both accept the file without complaint.

Comment: Please post this to the `pdftex` mailing list or bug tracker. It's not really suitable for a question & answer site. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2622/questions-which-are-bug-reports

Comment: I frequently have (with older and current versions of `pdftex`) the issue that the PDF resulting from a complex beamer presentation with lots of TikZ stuff is malformed. It cannot be opened (on OSX) by Skim, Preview, or Adobe Acrobat. This just occurs once in a while and a simply deleting and rebuilding has so far always helped.

Comment: I was able to work around the problem by putting \pdfminorversion=4 at the top of my .cls file to force pdf 1.4 output. I'll report the bug in iText.

Comment: Reported the iText bug here: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=1359559246.96119.YahooMailNeo%40web160501.mail.bf1.yahoo.com&forum_name=itext-questions The problem may just be that ubuntu and pdftk are using an out of date version of iText.

Comment: The bug is actually in a fork of iText called itext-paulo, which is what's used in pdftk.

Comment: Bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libitext-java/+bug/1110674

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [pdf](http://www.lightandmatter.com/pdftk_bug/me.pdf) you put online is a perfectly valid PDF 1.5 - so says Adobe Acrobar X Preflight.
[image: Acrobat X Preflight]

Starting with [PDF 1.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#File_structure), PDFs can contain compressed object streams. Please update you version of pdftk or file a bug [with them](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

Comment: Thanks. This would actually be a big in iText, which is the library pdftk uses.

Answer (score 2):

The version of iText that is used dates from 2006. See http://itextpdf.com/history/?branch=10&node=14

The file can be read without any problem using the latest version of iText. The other answers make it clear that the assumption that there's an error in the PDF file was wrong.

Either you're experiencing a bug in that obsolete version of iText (please read http://lowagie.com/itext2 for more info), or maybe there's something in the PDF that wasn't supported by iText at that time.

For instance: I see that the PDF uses a compressed XRef-table. I know that some PdfTk versions have problems with such files. Note that PdfTk is merely a wrapper around iText made by somebody who isn't affiliated in any way with the iText Group.

It's a pity you don't bother that person instead of the TeX and the iText people. You should alway ;-)

Comment: Hi and [Welcome to TeX-SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  It's great that you came by to clear up where the problem lay.  Generally people on this site are non-experts so we do our best to help each other out to narrow down problems but when it comes to genuine bugs we often have to just guess where the problem lies, hence no-one being all that sure where it lay, and many people might not know the relationship between pdftk and iText so might guess incorrectly.  If you look around the site you'll see that pdftk - and by extension iText - is highly regarded!

Comment: The page you linked to says: "iText Software Group has done a significant investment in identifying and eliminating all those case as of version 5.1. which is one of the reason why it is now a paying commercial version." Does this mean that the latest version is no longer open source, or are you just trying to say that it's under a dual licensing scheme? LGPL is compatible with commercial use. If 5.1 is still open source, and the problem is that ubuntu is still shipping an obsolete version, then I could file a bug report with ubuntu.

Comment: @BenCrowell: All these questions are answered on the [iText homepage](http://itextpdf.com). The free license is AGPL3, btw. Questions which are mainly about iText or pdftk are off-topic here and better suited at [so].

Comment: +1 for the reference to StackOverflow. I'm actively following all questions tagged with itext, itextsharp and itextpdf there. Should itext-related questions turn up here, please let me know.